# Facebook PHP SDK - Web App is working on one machine but not any others?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am on the verge of going crazy I think!

I am logged into my Personal Facebook account on my work machine and the app I am using works fine but on any other machine logged in as me, the app admin or anyone else the page just seems to keep on constantly refreshing with the state parameter in the url just whirring away and changing between page loads. (I have a laptop sitting on my desk, both using Firefox aswell)

I'm sure it was working on all machines that tested it the other day. Today it started with an error but I can't remember the error code but it was to do with the re-direct url not being owned by the domain but this doesn't seem to crop up now.

I am not the admin of the app either.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<?
error_reporting(0); 

// Facebook PHP SDK
include_once "src/facebook.php";

// app id and seret from the facebook app
$appId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';   
$secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $appId,
    'secret' => $secret,
    'cookie' => true,
));

//Facebook Authentication part
$user       = $facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'canvas'    => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'scope'     => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos'
    )
);

if ($user)
{
    try
    {
            // page id and the feed we want
    $user_feed = $facebook->api('PAGENUMBER/feed');

    echo "<div id=\"graph\">";
    $count = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<25; $i++)
    {
        // only want statuses - no videos, events, links etc.
        if ($user_feed['data'][$i]['type'] == "status")
                // just grabbing stuff and echoing it out
                // blah blah blah
            }
        } 
    catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {
            $user = null;
        }
    // close graph div
    echo "</div>";
}

// if the user is not logged in then redirect to login page
if (!$user)
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Just a note: don't use PHP short-tags.

Comment: thanks, I usually don't, can't remember if that was me or not. Changed now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a pain but took out the `if ($user)` and the `try` `catch` and the login redirect and all that seemed to work.